# How to implement Youtube like swipeable Bottomsheet in android?

Tags: android, youtube, material-design, draggable, bottom-sheet

I want to implement swipeable bottomsheet by swiping anywhere in the screen like in Youtube App in full screenmode . When we drag anywhere in screen then a bottomsheet gets drag up.

[image: Youtube like]

Comment: Were you able to find out ?

Comment: no , i did some other way using padding @coding_idiot

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61879381/how-to-drag-bottomsheet-from-anywhere-in-the-screen